# How to bind decimal value?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm getting an error:

> Default value did not match return type
>
> Parameter name: defaultValue

I've created a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

CustomCell.cs:

```
class CustomCell : ViewCell
{
    private readonly Label _label;

    public static readonly BindableProperty DecimalDataProperty = BindableProperty.Create("DecimalData", typeof(decimal), typeof(CustomCell), "DecimalData");

    public decimal DecimalData
    {
        get { return (decimal)GetValue(DecimalDataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DecimalDataProperty, value); }
    }

    public CustomCell()
    {
        _label = new Label { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Label)) };

        _label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding(path: "DecimalData", stringFormat: "{0}"));


        var horizontalStack = new StackLayout
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            HeightRequest = 35,
            Padding = new Thickness(10, 0, 10, 0)
        };

        horizontalStack.Children.Add(_label);

        View = horizontalStack;
    }
}
```

Page1.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:app8="clr-namespace:App8;assembly=App8"
             x:Class="App8.Page1">
  <ListView x:Name="listView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <app8:CustomCell DecimalData="{Binding DecimalData}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

Page1.xaml.cs:

```
public class Model
{
    public decimal DecimalData { set; get; }
}
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var list = new List<Model>
            {
                new Model {DecimalData = 565},
                new Model {DecimalData = 876},
                new Model {DecimalData = 123}
            };

            listView.ItemsSource = list;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

The question is simple: how do I bind decimal value to the custom ViewCell?

Could it be a bug?

Comment: please, notify if you could reproduce the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the two Create methods listed on the [Xamarin developer site for `BindableProperty`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty/) the fourth parameter is the default value for the property.

For a `decimal` this should be a numeric value (probably 0) but you are passing in the name of the property ("DecimalData") again.

Replace the second "DecimalData" with `0` or (as the parameter is an object so you have to be more explicit) `0m`

Comment: changed the code accordingly, the problem didn't go away. have you tried it?

Comment: changing `0` to `0m` or `double.Parse("0")` made it. you were right.

Comment: SORRY, I meant `decimal.Parse("0")`